# Form validation with click event

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a form with validation:

```
       <form role="form" method="POST" action="" >
            <input type="password" class="form-control top-buffer-sm" placeholder="Password" name="password" required autofocus></input>
            <input type="email" class="form-control top-buffer-sm" placeholder="Email" name="email" required autofocus></input>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button id="createUser" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

My submit button has an id and i need to do some other functionality before i submit the form:

```
      $('#createUser').click(function(){
            //check to see if validation passed
             //do custom stuff
             //now make ajax call

             $.ajax();
        });
```

but if the form is not valid, my ajax call is still being made, of course resulting in a server error. How do i check to see if the form passed the validation when i click the submit button? Thanks

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless the question is about the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org).

Answer (score 2):

Why not list to the submit event on the form?

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="" id="myForm">
```

Then:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(event) {
  // Prevent form submission on click
  event.preventDefault();

  // Write the code the determins if the form is valid.
  // `this` refers to the form.
  if (formIsValidCondition) {
    // do Ajax call here
  } else {
    // Do return a response to the user
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: @Mohamed - thanks for replying. bootstrap does the validation automatically. With the click event tied to my button, an ajax call will still be made despite the fact the form isnt valid. How do i check if the form passed bootstrap validation is my question.

Comment: @BoundForGlory Bootstrap has no built in client side validation library. So unless I misunderstand you, this isn't possible. Bootstrap doesn't validate anything. Are you using a 3rd party library on top?

Comment: @Mohamed - yes jquery does have built in validation not bootstrap http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/1113/

Comment: @BoundForGlory I think you are mistaken. You are confusing Chrome's HTML 5 with jQuery/Bootstrap validation. Bootstrap has absolutely no validation whatsoever, not it should. It's a CSS framework. jQuery does not either. It's a client side JavaScript library where frameworks and other JS tools are built on top it. What you are seeing is Chrome's HTML 5 default validations. You can get rid of those by removing the word `required` from the input definition.

Comment: @BoundForGlory, yes, like Mohamad said, you are confusing the HTML5 validation built into some browsers with a plugin.  Neither Bootstrap nor jQuery have validation unless you download another script.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my answer:

```
$('#createUser').click(function(){
      var valid = $("form").valid();
      if (valid)///keep on trucking
```

Comment: `valid()` is not a jQuery function. It's part of jQuery Validate, which is a separate library for validation, built on top of jQuery.